# Request for assistance with Guidewire, Claims Center, TYPE column and PAYMENT vs PAYEMENT

Tags: payment, claims, guidewire

Thanks for your help with this! I've a question about a specific column in Claims Center, [TYPE].

The TYPE column identifies record entries as Cash Payments, Rserves, Written Premiums, etc. I noticed there is one type, "PAYEMENT", that seems odd. I was told this is a non-issue, that it is a misspelling in all of Guidewire systems. Is that correct?

I see TYPE contains both "PAYMENT" and "PAYEMENT" and would like to understand the difference. Thank you again in advance for your support to this question.

I am mapping data lineage in efforts to track dependencies and validate attributes as they propagate through various transformation levels. I am seeking to understand why there are PAYMENTs and PAYEMENTs listed as 2 separate classifications for the TYPE column. I was told this is not specific to a particular organization, and that it is a misspelling across all Guidewire instances. Is this correct? If so, may I get a reference number for the known issue?

Comment: Can you please add some additional context to this question?  I checked a recent ootb version of claimcenter and the string 'payement' doesn't appear anywhere in the configuration.  Can you share the exact version you are looking at and what file contains the 'payement' string?  While it's feasible this was an error in earlier releases of the product it's more likely this was an error in your local configuration that can't be removed since it's been deployed to production.

Comment: hi @MartinAavik, thanks for the quick response! Is this the information you are looking for? | Application Version: 10.2.2.1574
Platform Version: 10.202.2
Schema Version: 670
Customer Version: 2.0.9.0 | If the error is on the local configuration side, would you happen to have trouble shooting documentation on your side I can bring to the team on this side?

Comment: I couldn’t see this typo either in the base configuration of ClaimCenter v10.2.2. Can you confirm if this was added by the customer?  What is the name of the entity / typelist where you are seeing this typo? I would do a compare with base on it to ascertain if it was added later, and then focus on its usages / references before thinking of a clean up in prod.